# Checking all code paths in a project written in a scripting language for syntax-correctness

Tags: python, ruby, scripting, powershell-2.0

This question applies to dynamically interpreted code, I guess

**In detail**

Say I have a set of data processing projects that depend on a common module called `tools`. Down the road of development, I find out that I want to change the interface of one of the functions or methods in `tools`.

This interface-change might not be totally backwards compatible, it might break a subset of my data processing projects.

If all the software involved would have to be compiled, I could simple re-compile everything and the compiler would point me to the spots where I have to adapt the calling code to the new signature. But how can this be done in an interpreted situation?

**TL;DR**

A set of script programs depend on a script module. After chaning the interface of the module in a possibly not backwards-compatible way, how do I check the dependent programs and make them compliant to the new interface?

Comment: This is why you should write tests.

Comment: I usually use the compiler to test syntax correctness. How to do this for scripting languages in a systematic way?

Comment: In ruby TDD is a must have. Having high test coverage ensures that every single line of code is executed when you run the test suite. There is no compiler in ruby, there is only a parser which will only raise an issues like missing end, bracket or similar. Since it is not possible for parser to say whether the method exists or not (as it might not exist yet, but will exist in the future or even it might trigger method_missing logic) tests are the only way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer is 'write tests'. For purely syntactical checking with some code correctness, like calling a function which does not exist like you are describing, `pylint` is probably the best tool. Install it with `pip install pylint`.